# Is there a API for Simple-Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia-api

I am looking for the API for [Simple-Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page). Is the Wikipedia API [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/) is the same one I need? I am a bit confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the API should work with this library as well, as long as it supports all Wikipedia versions. The "language code" you should use for simple Wikipedia would be `simple`, instead of, e.g., `en` for the english Wikipedia.

You can find a list of supported wikis, as per the documentation of the API, [here](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedias). The column "Wiki" is the information you need to pass as the language code.

Example (based on the documentation):

```py
import wikipediaapi
    wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('simple')

    page_py = wiki_wiki.page('Programming_language')
```

Comment: That was helpful thanks

Comment: When downvoting, it would be very nice to get a comment as well about what I can improve in my answer :) (not to you @Jack